# как сгенерировать строку на всю HTML страницу

Tags: javascript, html

как сделать так чтобы одна и та же строка сгенерировалась с самого начала и до конца HTML страницы используя JS? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

типа как тут, но еще длиннее, чтобы нужно было долго листать вниз.

Comment: Извините, что Вы имеете в виду?.. из вопросо не ясно что Вам нужно

Comment: прикрепил пример в описании

Comment: Что мешает сделать это циклом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#block')

while (el.offsetHeight < window.innerHeight) {
  el.innerHTML += 'Строка <br>'
}
```

```html
<div id="block">

</div>
```

или

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#block')

while (el.offsetHeight < window.innerHeight) {
  el.textContent += 'Строка '
}
```

```html
<div id="block">

</div>
```

Удачи!

UPDATE: Можно и без цикла, если использовать [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#block')
const count = window.innerHeight / el.offsetHeight

el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.repeat(count)
```

```html
<div id="block">
  Строка <br>
</div>
```

Comment: уу благодарю! выручили :)